# PL/SQL Invalid Identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql

While creating a trigger on the 'emprunter' table, I'm trying to compare a value coming from another table 'exemplaire.numexemplaire' which is supposed to be an INTEGER. But I keep getting the same errors which is:

- Error(4,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
- Error(7,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "EMPRUNTER"."NUMEXEMPLAIRE":
  invalid identifier

How can I do to retrieve the value of a field coming from another table (exemplaire.numexemplaire)?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BIEmprunter
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF numexemplaire ON emprunter
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
      livreEmpruntable    INTEGER;
BEGIN 
      SELECT  exemplaire.empruntable 
      INTO    livreEmpruntable
      FROM    exemplaire  
      WHERE   emprunter.numexemplaire = exemplaire.numexemplaire;

  IF livreEmpruntable != 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'exemplaire non empruntable');
  END if;
END;
```

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for the answer but I keep getting this error whule trying to test the trigger...

```
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'EQUIPE10.ABONNEMENTPASAJOUR' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

**Update 2**
Thanks again for the answer, the trigger can compile now. But when now I'm trying to make it work when inserting value but I keep getting the error because there is no data yet...

```
INSERT INTO emprunter
  VALUES (2, 1, 18, '17-02-01', null);

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "EQUIPE10.BIEMPRUNTER", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EQUIPE10.BIEMPRUNTER'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to join the two tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BIEmprunter
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF numexemplaire ON emprunter
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
      livreEmpruntable    INTEGER;
BEGIN 
      SELECT  exemplaire.empruntable 
      INTO    livreEmpruntable
      FROM exemplaire 
      join emprunter
        ON  emprunter.numexemplaire = exemplaire.numexemplaire;

  IF livreEmpruntable != 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'exemplaire non empruntable');
  END if;
END;
```

Also, the above join query can potentially return multiple rows and the call will result in exception (uncaught as of now)

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: Hi GurV, there were some issues with the code you've shared with me. Meanwhile, it changed the status of the problem, it's still not working. To make it easier for others to see the problem that I'm having, I made an update to my post !

Comment: @AndySantana - Can you try to recompile the trigger and post back the error that come up?

Comment: GurV, I made an update to my comment, but a bit too late. Please take a look at my edit :)

Comment: @Andy That's when you try to update/insert on the table. I am asking for compilation errors (as there obviously are). Just run the above code once and then run `show errors` to see the errors in compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use `:new` to access the record that triggered the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BIEmprunter
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF numexemplaire ON emprunter
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
      livreEmpruntable    INTEGER;
BEGIN 
      SELECT  exemplaire.empruntable 
      INTO    livreEmpruntable
      FROM    exemplaire  
      WHERE   :new.numexemplaire = exemplaire.numexemplaire;

  IF livreEmpruntable != 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'exemplaire non empruntable');
  END if;
END;
```

Comment: the trigger is compiling but when trying to test I get the error as explained on the update 2

Comment: @AndySantana That error means that no matching row exists in `exemplaire`,  what should happen in that case?